# Google Analytics V3 Php API not fetching the latest page views

Tags: php, laravel, google-analytics

I am trying to get the page views between 2 dates, by filtering using pagePath in google analytics v3 API.

Here is my code.

```
return $analytics->data_ga->get(
                    'ga:' . $profileId,
                    '2023-07-01',
                    '2023-07-27',
                    'ga:users,ga:pageviews,ga:uniquePageviews',
                    [
                        'dimensions' => 'ga:date,ga:pageTitle,ga:pagePath',
                        'filters'   => 'ga:pagePath=~/' . 'brilliant-earth',
                        'max-results' => 10000
                    ]
                );
```

I did visited the site everyday, but I am not getting the page views count after July 4th 2023. I can get data till July 4th 2023 only.

Here is the api response.

```json
    "rows":[

    [
        "20230701",
        "2023 Benefits",
        "\/brilliant-earth",
        "3",
        "4",
        "3"
    ],
    [
        "20230701",
        "401k",
        "\/brilliant-earth\/401k?country=us",
        "2",
        "4",
        "2"
    ],
    [
        "20230701",
        "404",
        "\/brilliant-earth\/empowermyretirement.com",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1"
    ],
    [
        "20230701",
        "Enroll in Benefits",
        "\/brilliant-earth\/enroll-in-benefits",
        "1",
        "2",
        "1"
    ],
    [
        "20230701",
        "Ginger Mental Wellness",
        "\/brilliant-earth\/ginger-mental-wellness?country=us",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1"
    ],
    [
        "20230702",
        "2023 Benefits",
        "\/brilliant-earth",
        "8",
        "15",
        "10"
    ],
    [
        "20230702",
        "401k",
        "\/brilliant-earth\/401k?country=us",
        "1",
        "2",
        "2"
    ],
    [
        "20230702",
        "Blue Shield Medical",
        "\/brilliant-earth\/blue-shield-medical\/compare_plans",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1"
    ],
    [
        "20230702",
        "Blue Shield Medical",
        "\/brilliant-earth\/blue-shield-medical?country=us",
        "3",
        "4",
        "3"
    ],
    [
        "20230702",
        "Commuter Benefits",
        "\/brilliant-earth\/commuter-benefits?country=us",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1"
    ],
    [
        "20230702",
        "EAP",
        "\/brilliant-earth\/eap?country=us",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1"
    ],
    [
        "20230702",
        "Ginger Mental Wellness",
        "\/brilliant-earth\/ginger-mental-wellness?country=us",
        "1",
        "2",
        "1"
    ],
    [
        "20230702",
        "Guardian Dental",
        "\/brilliant-earth\/guardian-dental?country=us",
        "1",
        "2",
        "1"
    ],
    [
        "20230702",
        "Travel Assistance",
        "\/brilliant-earth\/travel-assistance?country=us",
        "1",
        "3",
        "1"
    ],
    [
        "20230702",
        "Your Cost",
        "\/brilliant-earth\/your-cost",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1"
    ],
    [
        "20230703",
        "2023 Benefits",
        "\/brilliant-earth",
        "8",
        "10",
        "9"
    ],
    [
        "20230703",
        "401k",
        "\/brilliant-earth\/401k?country=us",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1"
    ],
    [
        "20230703",
        "Commuter Benefits",
        "\/brilliant-earth\/commuter-benefits?country=us",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1"
    ],
    [
        "20230703",
        "EAP",
        "\/brilliant-earth\/eap?country=us",
        "1",
        "2",
        "1"
    ],
    [
        "20230703",
        "Ginger Mental Wellness",
        "\/brilliant-earth\/ginger-mental-wellness?country=us",
        "2",
        "3",
        "3"
    ],
    [
        "20230704",
        "2023 Benefits",
        "\/brilliant-earth",
        "3",
        "3",
        "3"
    ],
    [
        "20230704",
        "401k",
        "\/brilliant-earth\/401k?country=us",
        "3",
        "3",
        "3"
    ],
    [
        "20230704",
        "404",
        "\/brilliant-earth\/empowermyretirement.com",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1"
    ],
    [
        "20230704",
        "Enroll in Benefits",
        "\/brilliant-earth\/enroll-in-benefits",
        "2",
        "2",
        "2"
    ],
    [
        "20230704",
        "Your Cost",
        "\/brilliant-earth\/your-cost",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1"
    ]

]
```

I have a couple of questions:

- What are the limitations for getting data with this API?
- Should I use GA V4 reporting API?

But it is asking for View ID. I am not using Universal Analytics, and I am using GA only.

Comment: You write: _"But it is asking for View ID"_ - What do you mean by that?